# How to decrease CPU load aggregation to 1s instead of 10s in cAdvisor?

Tags: performance, docker, kubernetes, monitoring, cadvisor

I'm using Kubernetes latest version (bare-metal on a multi-node cluster), and I can get cAdivsor metrics using Kubernetes metrics API. I can see cAdvisor provides `container_cpu_load_average_10s` metric which from its name, it is the aggregation of CPU loads in 10s.

Is there any way I can reduce this `aggregation/granularity` time to 1s? (having something like `container_cpu_load_average_1s`)

P.S: API Endpoint that I'm using is `https://<my_k8s_ip>:6443/api/v1/nodes/kubernetes3/proxy/metrics/cadvisor`

**UPDATE:** I just find out there is a `--housekeeping_interval` parameter but need to find out if it is the way to go, and if so then how can I change it in my current Kubernetes deployment. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need to update your deployment. `--housekeeping_interval` is parameter of `kubelet` . You need just add `--housekeeping_interval=1s` to startup script of `kubelet`. Config file for start `kubelet` is usually located in `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf`.
Just update the string:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_SYSTEM_PODS_ARGS $KUBELET_NETWORK_ARGS $KUBELET_DNS_ARGS $KUBELET_AUTHZ_ARGS $KUBELET_CADVISOR_ARGS $KUBELET_CERTIFICATE_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS --housekeeping_interval=1s
```

Add the `--housekeeping_interval=1s` at the end, and restart kubelet. You need to do this on all nodes.

Comment: Yes @Nick I just end up to this solution a few minutes ago. But I’m not sure if it really have any effect on the final result  I mean cAdvisor output seems still updating every 10s...still testing

Comment: [@Michel Gokan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169545/michel-gokan) cAdvisor  compiled in kubelet and it must affect it, but you should add this to all kubelets in cluster. and don't forget to restart kubelet

Answer (score 0):

We should set two arguments in `10-kubeadm.conf`:

1. `--enable-load-reader`
2. `--housekeeping_interval=1s`